# Could not return String/Ajax output it jump to viewresolver "Could not resolve view with name xyz......."

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/time.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String getTime(@RequestParam String name) {
    String result = "Time for " + name + " is " + new Date().toString();
    return result;
  }
```

// my configuratin are :

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
```

and jsp is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjax() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'time.html',
        data: ({name : "me"}),
        success: function(data) {
          $('#time').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
<button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
<div id="time">
```

Its gives that output : 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'Time for me is Tue Nov 01 16:54:04 IST 2016' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Do you have view named "Time for me is Tue Nov 01 16:54:04 IST 2016 " ?    Return Name of view .i.e. JSP Page name